# get multiple data from webservice using SOAP in android

Tags: android, soap

Im getting single data from web service using SOAP in android and displayed well.But when i need to retrieve multiple set of values from web services..How could i do that?For ex.from a webservice.,im getting 10 set of student records with fields stu.Name,stuRegno.,stuAge.After getting response of this.,i need to parse it to stored into local db with corresponding field names.How could i do that?

My code:

```
 public class Main extends Activity {
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "TopGoalScorers";
     private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu/data/TopGoalScorers";
     private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu";
     private static final String URL = "http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu/data/info.wso?WSDL";

    //Called when the activity is first created. 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

            //Buttons deaktiviert alles automatisch

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            request.addProperty("iTopN", 3);// username von Preferences abgeholt
            //request.addProperty("intB", 4);


            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), request.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport (URL);             
            try {
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                //Parse Response
                SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
                String xy = resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty(0).toString();
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblStatus)).setText(xy); 


            } catch(Exception E) {

                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblStatus)).setText("ERROR:" + E.getClass().getName() + ": " + E.getMessage());

            }
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what is your problem. You need to convert  resultsRequestSOAP to appropriate data format(for example String) and parse it(for example through SAX) and in your parser collect all data in a container(for example List).